# How to do this counting problem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

I know that the pigeonhole principle is to be applied here but I can’t see yet how.

On a certain planet in the solar system Tau Cetus, more than half the surface of the planet is dry land. Show that the Tau Cetans can dig a tunnel straight through the centre of the planet, beginning and ending on dry land.

Comment: Suppose otherwise. Then note that, to every point on the surface which is dry, there is another equivalent point on the other side of the planet which is water. Apply this to every point on dry land. Then you reach a contradiction: $>50\%$ is dry but also $>50\%$ is water.

Comment: Although you might have been assigned this question to get you thinking about the ideas behind the pigeonhole principle, this isn't really a discrete-math problem.  Eevee Trainer (in a comment) and Rezha Adrian Tanuharja (in an answer) have explained how to solve this using a proof by contradiction, but without using the pigeonhole principle, and you can't expect an answer that uses it in a rigorous way.

Comment: You can prove it rigorously using the pigeonhole principle (I believe I have) but I think you have to use the set and function definition which is compatible with infinite sets. You may be able to make an argument using the more common counting-based version which you can say should hold as the number of points you consider gets large, but I doubt this would go through rigorously.

Comment: So can I think of it this way too — Let ‘Start’ and ‘End’ be two pigeonholes, and we consider the starting and ending points of all possible tunnels as the pigeons. Since >half of the planet is dry, if we think of a dry starting point and it’s equivalent wet ending point, theoretically, we will eventually run out of wet ending points, i.e. the ‘Start’ pigeonhole must have at least one more point than the ‘End’ pigeonhole, so we will end up having two dry points to make a tunnel with?

Comment: That is the intuition behind the inner workings of my argument, the only thing is I think you have to be careful about talking about "running out" of points because the set of points on a sphere is uncountably infinite, which is why I resort to the function-based argumentation which leaves less room for weird infinite set things to ruin your day.

Answer (score 2):

If dry land is always opposite of non dry land, then the area of wet land must be at least equal to area of dry land. But the area of dry land itself is already more than half the area of the planet. If you don't like paraphrasing, check out the following alternative:

Let $S$ be the whole planet, $G$ be all dry land and $G'$ be all land opposite of dry land. Suppose that $G\cap G'=\varnothing$
$$
\begin{align}
A(S)&\geq A(G\cup G')\\
&=A(G)+A(G')-A(G\cap G')\\
&=2A(G)
\end{align}
$$

This contradict $2A(G)>A(S)$

Answer (score 1):

Proof by contradiction: let's suppose that there was no way to dig a tunnel through the center of the planet starting on dry land which also ends on dry land. This means that for each point on dry land, the point on the opposite side of the planet cannot be dry.

Let's define a function $O(p)$ which acts on the domain of points on the planet which lie on dry land. By our reasoning before, the codomain must consist of entirely wet land. It should be clear that $O$ is injective because each point can only be opposite to exactly one point on the planet.

However, the pigeonhole principle states that there cannot exist an injective function whose domain is larger than its codomain, and the problem tells us that there is more dry land than wet land. Therefore, we have reached a contradiction and there must be some way to dig a tunnel through the center of the planet which starts and ends on dry land.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I’m unable to understand “the pigeonhole principle states that there cannot exist an injective function whose co-domain is larger than its domain.” I know injective functions can have co-domain larger than the domain.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I think it's supposed to be "whose domain is larger than its codomain." I think my source had it the wrong way around and then I also read it the wrong way around. My apologies, correcting it now. Edit: okay actually I just noticed what happened, I accidentally mistyped larger instead of smaller.

Comment: Yes, it is clear now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I shall reformulate this into a coloring problem as follows:

> Consider a spherical shell $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the points on whose surface are colored with either one of **black** $(B)$ or **white** $(W)$ colors. If more than half of the shell is colored black, show that it is possible to find a line through the center of the shell that joins two black points.

**Some notation:**

- For a point $p$, I shall denote its diametrically opposite point by $p'$. Note that $(p')' = p$. We shall also call $p'$ as the *tunnel-complement* of $p$.
- For every point $p\in S$, I will denote its color by $c(p)$. In general, $c(p)\in\{B,W\}$

We shall complete the proof by way of *contradiction*.
Suppose it is not possible to dig such a tunnel, i.e. there does not exist $p$ such that $c(p) = c(p') = B$.

So, for every $p\in S$ such that $c(p) = B$, we have $c(p') = W$.

Consider the sets:

- $\mathcal{B} = \{p\in S: c(p) = B\}$
- $\mathcal{W} = \{p\in S: c(p) = W\}$
- $\mathcal{B}':= \{p': p\in \mathcal{B}\} $
- $\mathcal{W}':= \{p': p\in \mathcal{W}\} $

We know that $c(p) = W$ for all $p\in \mathcal{B}'$, i.e. all elements diametrically opposite to black elements must be white. It is also clear that $\mathcal{B}\cap\mathcal{W} = \emptyset$ and $\mathcal{B}\cup\mathcal{W} = S$. Also, $|\mathcal{B}| = |\mathcal{B}'|$ and $|\mathcal{W}| = |\mathcal{W}'|$ i.e. the cardinality of a set and its *tunnel-complement* are the same. This is because there is an obvious bijection between the two, namely $$f:\mathcal{B}\to \mathcal{B}', p\mapsto p'$$ and $$g:\mathcal{W}\to \mathcal{W}', p\mapsto p'$$

We are given that more than half of the shell is colored black, so that $|\mathcal{B}| > |\mathcal{W}|$. Also, $\mathcal{B}' \subset \mathcal{W}$ since all elements opposite to black elements are white. So, $|\mathcal{B}'| \le |\mathcal{W}|$ which gives $|\mathcal{B}| \le |\mathcal{W}|$ from the bijection seen above.

So, we have $|\mathcal{B}| \le |\mathcal{W}|$ and $|\mathcal{B}| > |\mathcal{W}|$ - which is a contradiction. Hence, it is possible to dig the desired tunnel, i.e. we can find a point $p\in S$ such that $p,p'\in\mathcal{B}$.

Answer (score 0):

In this case there are uncountably many pigeonholes corresponding to all possible pairs of antipodes of the planet (endpoints of all tunnels) and a pigeon is an infinitesimally small patch of land. Since taking one end of each tunnel covers exactly half the planet's area and more than half the planet's surface is land, there must be a pigeonhole with two pigeons, i.e. suitable endpoints for a land-to-land tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

We can apply the pigeon hole principle by doing something like this:

First, discretize half the surface of the planet into n pigeon holes. Each pigeon hole can accept two items. First, we fill the pigeon holes with dry land. For any pigeon hole with only one item in it, we can now fill it with wet land.

If we have k regions of dry land and k>n, then we'll have to fill an additional (k-n) pigeon holes with a 2nd region of dry land. Now, we have less than n pigeon holes to fill with wet land which corresponds to less than half of the surface being covered with water.

Each pigeon hole containing two areas of dry land corresponds to positions where you can
start digging in dry land and reach another area of dry land. This only occurs when k>n or in other words, when more than half of the surface is dry.